# ExceptionHandling mischief

Tags: java, exception

Java gives compile time error if we don't write try catch block or try finally block or pass the Exception to it's calling Function for checked exception.That is all fine.But,My Question is Why then catch block is made optional i.e. we can write try block then finally block so,It this not a dirty thing to so..Please correct me if I am wrong somewhere..

Comment: Im sorry but are you saying that in `try{}catch{}finally{}` the `catch` clouse is optional??? Never heard of it. I would say it IS mandatory and finally is optional.

Comment: @Antoniossss Yes catch is optional..It correct we can write try{}finally{}..If it is checked Exception we have to handle in calling Function for unchecked it's fine..Compiler will not complain about same..Please see link for more details. http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-02-1997/jw-02-hood.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- A calling method can also handle the exception
- `finally` block allowed because there may be some code which should be run even if exception is thrown. You may want to close some database connection or resources even if exception is thrown.

Answer (score 2):

You MAY omit a `catch` block if the methods in you try blocks throw an **unchecked exception**.

Unchecked exceptions have a special treatment in Java:

- if you throw one, you are not compelled to declare that your method `throws` it;
- if you invoke a method which throws one, whether it be in a try block or otherwise, you are not compelled to `catch` it (nor to `throws` it, see above).

What is called "unchecked exception" in Java is clearly defined. All exceptions are ultimately `Throwable`s, and unchecked excetptions either inherit `Error` or `RuntimeException`.

Comment: @Antoniossss you are wrong about this. If you have a `finally` clause you _can_ omit `catch`. Please try it out if you still disagree

Comment: But this applies only to the unchecked exceptions.

Comment: @Antoniossss this is wrong if code in a `try` block only throws unchecked exceptions, if any. In this case, you MAY `catch` but you do not have to.

Comment: @fge why it is wrong? Eg. when using hibernate - session operations throws only unchecked exceptions which you should catch in order to rollback transaction;

Comment: @Antoniossss in this case I'd blame Hibernate for making such exceptions unchecked to begin with, but as always, YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

Try-finally is generally used to handle critical code to get executed. Something like **releasing of resources or lock on objects.** The intention here is not to handle exceptions but to make sure that even if some unexpected exception occurs **resources are released safely.** This is ensured as **finally block is executed in all the scenarios**. Only exception is JVM should not shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not a really clean/nice way to code, but you're telling the compiler you are aware that something *could* go wrong. That doesn't mean it good practice, but in the end it's your code. The reason the compiler bugs you about "try" is if you somehow oversaw it. This is special for unchecked exceptions. Read more about it here at Oracle http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html

Answer (score 0):

If you declare the exception (either checked or unchecked) in the method's signature, you are not forced to have a catch clause for your try block. In the case of an unchecked exception, you even do not need to declare it.

Nevertheless, you often need to free or release resources, independent whether an exception occurred or not. So you could write this:

```
public void someMethod() throws IOException {
    Object resource = getSomeResource();
    try {
        // Imagine, all following calls could throw an IOException
        workWithResource(resource);
        continueWorkWithResource(resource);
        stillDoSomeWorkOnResource(resource);
    } finally {
        releaseResource(resource);
    }
}
```

Even if one of the method throws an IOException, the resource is release prior to propagating the exception to the method's caller. In case of no exception, the resource is also released.

**A finally block is executed always.**